# Задача про ресторан

Tags: python, олимпиада

**Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, желательно на python, но можно просто объяснить как это решать**

> (без циклов)

Ресторан
В одном курином ресторане можно купить:

1 ножку + 1 крыло,

1 ножку + 1 бедро,

1 бедро,

2 крыла,

3 крыла.

Требуется определить, можно ли купить ровно k крыльев, n ножек и b бедер.

Входные данные

Вводятся три числа k, n, b. Все числа целые неотрицательные, не превосходящие 100.

Выходные данные

Выведите слово YES, если купить указанный набор можно, NO — если нельзя (заглавными латинскими буквами).

Примеры

> Ввод 0 6 0 Вывод NO
>
> Ввод 2 3 1 Вывод YES

Comment: Да вы что двинулись с этой задачей что-ли ?!:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091844/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091307/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9